# Category coming at inappropriate place

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I worked on [this](http://toolskaart.com/index.php/pcd-inserts.html) and it is live now. Please have a look at it. The problem is that the category named "Carbide rod" is not assigned to that "PCD inserts" category. But still showing. I don't know whats the problem in it. Please help me on it.[image: backend]

Comment: Simply dragging and dropping category is not working?

Comment: No. I don't want that "carbide rod" to show inside "PCD inserts". But it showing. I linked it in the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have enabled flat tables to be used on front, which is generally a good idea. The thing to remember, though, is to perform a Category Flat Data re-index in Admin Panel. Go to System > Index Management and do a reindex of Category Flat Data.

Next you should Flush Cache Storage at System > Cache Management.

If that won't help, then check how your category tree looks on a Store View level. Magento allows to have different category trees for each store view.

[image]

Comment: How to do that one. Please tell. I'm don't know about it.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show where you can change the scope

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Carbide rods category is not displayed under PCD inserts, whats your question exactly I'm not getting it.

Comment: as you can see in the picture I've attached, I assigned carbide rod to "tungsten carbide rods". But it is also showing once we click "pcd inserts". But I haven't assigned "carbide rods" to "pcd inserts".